# Tuning-up WCF-web service for minimal response time

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing WCF service that will be called synchronously from web server and it response will be used to define the start page content so this will  influence start page load time directly. 
Now it is planned that this WCF service will be hosted inside VM inside the same server where the site web server is hosted. Now there is one sync method method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> GetDataPositions(Guid userId, List<string> refsList, Guid sessionId);
```

Sure I want to minimize page load time. Back-end code is very well optimized. But I am not so experienced in tuning WCF. What would I do to make total response time 
WebServer->WCF-service inside VM->WebServer as minimal as possible? I know that WCF serialization/deserialization can be not so fast as expected. How to avoid that?
What are other possibles problems and ways for optimization? I found the general articles about general WCF optimization but want to know what advices will be useful in this case. Will the WCF web-service  give good enough response time for this case? `"If an e-commerce site is making $100,000 per day, a 1 second page delay could potentially cost you $2.5 million in lost sales every year."` (That e-commerce web server have a lot of users- several millions web sessions per day.)

Comment: Well, first is to try and set up the binding so that it is TCP/IP Binary bindings. This will indeed increase the communication speed. However as you said, you cannot help the time it takes for serialization. Also the WCF method calls you have should be optimised for a quick process/response time. Also use caching wherever possible.